# Question about inverse kinematics for 2 axis gimbal

Tags: kinematics, inverse-kinematics

If I have a 2 axis gimbal (pitch and yaw) and I want to set the camera to a specific inertial orientation (in the world frame), how can I do this? How do I know what to set each motor to achieve this?
I'm having trouble finding resources, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* a9n1s. I don't understand your question as it is presented here. How are you getting the target orientation? You're stating that you have the ability to control pitch and yaw, so it would sound like your question is, "How do I calculate pitch and yaw angles from a given rotation representation?" Is this correct? There are answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37558238/5171120) that describe getting RPY angles from a rotation matrix or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18115837/5171120) for getting RPY angles from quaternions.

Comment: If those answers aren't helpful, please *edit your question* to clarify what you're trying to do and the issues you've faced when trying to use methods like the ones I link above.

Comment: I don't have a rotation matrix representation of the desired orientation. The target orientation is given to me (in the world frame) as azimuth and elevation. I'm looking to calculate the pitch and yaw of the gimbal's 2 axis that will bring it to the target orientation.

Comment: Isn't azimuth your yaw and elevation your pitch? Can you not just use those two angles directly? Or are you saying that you have a gimbal base that is offset from the world frame somehow, and you need to know how to modify the azimuth and elevation angles to account for the offset? I know sometimes it's difficult to ask good questions because you may have been thinking about the problem for days or even weeks at this point, but it's important to include a clear problem statement for everyone else to understand the issue you're trying to resolve.